# docker ubuntu container exec does not replace command

Tags: bash, docker

I'm trying to build container for openshift. One of their requirements is that the main process is pid 1. In order to so your starting shell script should use exec to replace the shell script. For our application we are using Tomcat, so I have no chance to replace the catalina.sh properly but to use it, as it does use exec, but the command does not get replaced. So I simplified the the container down, and the problem still persists:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ADD test.sh /root/test.sh
RUN chmod a+x /root/test.sh

CMD /root/test.sh
```

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /bin/sleep 3600
```

I build the container with `docker build -t test .`
If I now run the container with `docker run --name test-ub test` and then execute `docker top test-ub -ef` it shows:

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                109019              108989              0                   16:50               ?                   00:00:00            /bin/sh -c /root/test.sh
root                109057              109019              0                   16:50               ?                   00:00:00            /bin/sleep 3600
```

Two Processes which should not be the case! If I replace the `FROM ubuntu:18.04` with `FROM centos:centos7` it works as expected, only one process:

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                105946              105916              0                   16:19               ?                   00:00:00            /bin/sleep 3600
```

So I think the problem lies somewhere in Ubuntu, but I have no idea where.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [same question with good answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52968361/different-process-are-running-as-pid-1-when-running-cmd-entrypoint-in-shell-form).
I don't want to duplicate the answer, just give a short abstract:

The difference is between the default `sh`, which is `dash` in Ubuntu and `bash` in CentOS.
If you run your command with `bash` it will work as expected:

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/root/test.sh"]
```